# iPhone: thumbnail gets bigger on tap in Retina

Tags: iphone

When tapping an item(UITableView) on a iPhone 4 (retina display) the thumbnail becomes larger which have  editButtonItem.

```
[cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(7, 7, 30, 30)];
cell.imageView.image=objPhotoAlbumIcon;
```

Updated:

To solved this issue i have used custom image view but the problem is edit image comes over custom  image while editing.

```
UIImageView * cusomtomImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
cusomtomImageView.frame=CGRectMake(7, 7, 30, 30);
cusomtomImageView.image=objPhotoAlbumIcon;
cell addSubview:cusomtomImageView];
[cusomtomImageView release];
```

I need some suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some few hours ,i fixed the above issue by using custom image and label in editing mode.
just need to add cell.contentView.

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:cusomtomImageView];
```

here is the code

```
UIImageView * cusomtomImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
cusomtomImageView.frame=CGRectMake(7, 7, 29, 29);
cusomtomImageView.image=objPhotoAlbumIcon;
[cell.contentView addSubview:cusomtomImageView];
[cusomtomImageView release];


UILabel *cusomtextlebel=[[UILabel alloc] init];
cusomtextlebel.frame=CGRectMake(45, 8, 180, 24);
cusomtextlebel.text=subPhotoAlbumTitle;
[cusomtextlebel setFont:[OntdekZeelandFonts getFontForObjectLabel]];
cusomtextlebel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cusomtextlebel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:cusomtextlebel];
[cusomtextlebel release];
```